# Set statistics target for MCV extended statistic

Tags: postgresql

I have an MCV statistic like so:

```
create statistics stat1 (mcv) on col_a,col_b,col_c from table_a;
```

When I query `pg_stats_ext`, I see that I have only 82 combinations recorded in column `most_common_vals`.

But the combination of value that I am trying to fix a query for is not in the list of recorded combinations:

```
select * from table_a where col_a = 'X' and col_b = 'Y' and col_c = 'Z';
```

How can I increase the number of recorded combinations?

Can a statistics target be set for extended statstics like it can be done for individual columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that with [`ALTER STATISTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterstatistics.html):

```
ALTER STATISTICS stat1 SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Comment: this is it. thank you very much!